# Date and time store error in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the 14 digits number 27122013113700 I will get to store as data and time format in mysql. Format need to be like 27-12-2013 11:37:00. Now it is storing as 00-00-00 00:00:00
Please tell me a simple code to solve this.

Comment: `27-12-2013 11:37:00` is not a valid mysql format the valid format is `2013-12-27 11:37:00`

Comment: Try this `$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s","27122013113700");`

Comment: it storing as this value 1947-08-25 19:31:00

Comment: It doesn't looks like timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format should be like this
2013-12-27 11:37:00
to save it into database with at datatype of datetime.

the code for that is this
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s','27122013113700');

hope it helps

I knew it

```
<?php

$string = 27122013113700;

$day = substr($string, 0, 2);
$month = substr($string, 2, 2);
$year = substr($string, 4, 4);

$hour = substr($string, 8, 2);
$min = substr($string, 10, 2);
$sec = substr($string, 12, 2);

$result = $day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year.' '.$hour.':'.$min.':'.$sec;

echo $result;
```

Copy and Paste it, and try it your self

Comment: it storing as this value 1947-08-25 19:31:00

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use Database Table Column datatype "DATETIME" and then change in your date format like  this :

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

It store the date in Y-m-d h:i:s format.

Best Luck

Answer (score 0):

`27122013113700` is not a valid datetime format. It looks close to a Unix timestamp, however `2013-12-27 11:37:00` converts to `1388169420`. The reason your are getting `00-00-00 00:00:00` and `1947-08-25 19:31:00` is for this reason, MYSQL can't recognize it as valid so it inserts a default value.

If you have a specific date you need to use, it will need to be done like this. PHP's DateTime class makes easy work of this, however you need version 5.2 to use it.

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-12-27 11:37:00');
$db_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you just need the current date, it's like this.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$db_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```